# How to run a function background in android?

Tags: android, android-listview

In my application I have a function to populate listview.I want to run this function periodically on every 5 minutes.I have used following method for that.

```
private class RefreshThread extends Thread{
        public boolean isStop = false;

        public void run(){
            try{
                while(!isStop){                                             
                    Headlines.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {                   
                        public void run() {
                              populate_listview(); //Function to populate listview
                        }
                    });                         
                    try{ Thread.sleep(300000); } catch(Exception ex){}
                }
        }catch(Exception e){
        }
      }
    }
```

when I use this method the function runs on foreground so the entire application got affected by this.I want to run this function in background so that the listview updates and the user never knows that the function is running.

following is the function to populate listview.

```
  public void populate_listview()
         {
                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> newsList = new            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_HEAD);
            // looping through all song nodes <song>
            NodeList itemLst = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
            String MarqueeStr="";

            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

                //map.put(KEY_DATE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DATE));

                newsList.add(map);
    }
```

Comment: for background activity you should use a component called **Service**

Comment: Im a noob in android and dont how to implement it..thats why I came here.. :) can you be more descriptive?

Comment: no problem, just search on google or SO "Android+Service" you will find good tutorials

Comment: You are running entire function `populate_listview`  on UI thread.So the thread you have created is of no use

Comment: What I supposed to do then? Dont I have to call the entire function to update my listview? Is there any other method so that the new items will be added to listview on specific time period?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get smaller performance overhead, you should do all the preparations, including populating `HashMap` with proper values, in your background thread and leave in `populate_listview()` method only `newList.add(refresh_thread.getMap());`. Just add to `RefreshThread` `synchronized` method `getMap()` to access this `HashMap` from another class, and another `synchronized` method `prepareHashMap()` for the code that prepare it. Obviously, your `HashMap` must be a field of `RefreshThread` class. Then, the `run()` method will look like this:

```
public void run(){
        try{
            while(!isStop){                                             
                prepareHashMap();
                Headlines.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {                   
                    public void run() {
                          populate_listview(); //Function to populate listview
                    }
                });                         
                try{ Thread.sleep(300000); } catch(Exception ex){}
            }
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to carry out your activity in background.

Here is a good [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can create an Android [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) for this purpose and use the Alarm Manager to invoke the service.

Here is a nice [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html)

Cheers,
RJ

Answer (score 1):

you need to explore the doInBackground function of AsyncTask class.

check out the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and this [example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html).